# Hide sqlcmd in c# application

Tags: c#, sqlcmd

I am new to c# and I'm rewriting my old batch file script into it but I've come across this problem:

Basically I want to hide sqlcmd window so I've tried this

```
        Process bkp = new Process();
        bkp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        bkp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        bkp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        bkp = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\90\\Tools\\Binn\\SQLCMD.EXE", "-S This-PC\\MyApp -U user -P pass -Q \"query\"");
```

But this doesn't work and the black window is still present. Is there a way to really hide it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You prepared the `bkp` object but it's not used at all. It gets overwritten at the moment when `Process.Start` method is called.

It should look like this:

```
  Process bkp = new Process();
  bkp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  bkp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  bkp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  bkp.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\90\\Tools\\Binn\\SQLCMD.EXE";
  bkp.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S This-PC\\MyApp -U user -P pass -Q \"query\"";
  bkp.Start();
```